# Regex to catch the main name of a file

Tags: python, regex, list, expression

I got stuck on regex to catch the main name of a file in the elements of a list. Suppose I have a list of filepath:

```
path_list = ['/Users/buggylines/histogram/offline-deployer-list_b7bacc7fdb-0e0e08077c_GERONIMO-2886_635_histogrambuglines_635.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/normal.jsp_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/hbase-env.sh_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/LICENSE-tesh_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo_dcce59ae71-8f5c1aa7a1_GERONIMO-5661_1554_histogrambuglines_54.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd_544dee5179-40a2ae1d41_GERONIMO-1027_131_histogrambuglines_131.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff'
            ]
```

I want to capture only the name of a file using `regex`. I need the following output:

```
expected_output = ['offline-deployer-list',
                   'normal.jsp',
                   'hbase-env.sh',
                   'LICENSE-tesh',
                   'geronimo',
                   'catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1',
                   'geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd',
                   '6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT'
                  ]
```

This is the code I have written:

```
filename = []
for z, path in enumerate(path_list):
     pattern = re.search("((?:\w+[-]\w+[-]\w+|\w+[-]\w+|\w+)[.]\w+[_])|(?<=histogram/)(?:\w+[-]\w+[-]\D+[_]|\D+[-]\w+[_])|(?<=histogram\/)(\w+[_])(?<=[_])", path)
     pattern = pattern.groups()
     filename.append(pattern[0])
```

However, the output isn't what I expected. This is the output of the code:

```
filename = [None,
            'normal.jsp_',
            'hbase-env.sh_',
            None,
            None,
            'jar.sha1_',
            '0.xsd_',
            'README.TXT_']
```

I need help to fix the regex. Thank you so much.

Comment: So you want the content between the last `/` and the `_`? Is regex the correct tool for this?

Comment: `[re.search(r'/histogram/([^_/]+)', x).group(1) for x in path_list]`

Comment: Yes, I need the content between the last `/` and the first `_`.

Comment: Then you just need `.*/([^_]+)`. That `((?<=\/)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(?!.+\/)(?=_))` looks too complex then what you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that works for me:

```
((?<=histogram\/)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(?=_))
```

Check it here
https://regex101.com/r/VfQIJC/4

**Update**

A more generic one which matches between the last / and the first _ after it is this:

```
((?<=\/)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(?!.+\/)(?=_))
```

https://regex101.com/r/VfQIJC/5

Comment: Sorry, your regex works well. But if the path contains `_`, it doesn't work. E.g. `/Users/analyze_geronimo/histogram/offline-deployer-list_b7bacc7fdb-0e0e08077c_GERONIMO-2886_635_histogrambuglines_635.diff`

Comment: Ah, great. It works and simpler than my regex. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use os.path.basename like so:

```
import os

path_list = ['/Users/buggylines/histogram/offline-deployer-list_b7bacc7fdb-0e0e08077c_GERONIMO-2886_635_histogrambuglines_635.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/normal.jsp_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/hbase-env.sh_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/LICENSE-tesh_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo_dcce59ae71-8f5c1aa7a1_GERONIMO-5661_1554_histogrambuglines_54.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd_544dee5179-40a2ae1d41_GERONIMO-1027_131_histogrambuglines_131.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff'
        ]

output = [os.path.basename(path).split('_')[0] for path in path_list]    

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['offline-deployer-list', 'normal.jsp', 'hbase-env.sh', 'LICENSE-tesh', 'geronimo', 'catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1', 'geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd', '6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT']
```

Comment: It works. But I need to use regex for my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
path_list = ['/Users/buggylines/histogram/offline-deployer-list_b7bacc7fdb-0e0e08077c_GERONIMO-2886_635_histogrambuglines_635.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/normal.jsp_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/hbase-env.sh_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/LICENSE-tesh_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo_dcce59ae71-8f5c1aa7a1_GERONIMO-5661_1554_histogrambuglines_54.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd_544dee5179-40a2ae1d41_GERONIMO-1027_131_histogrambuglines_131.diff',
             '/Users/buggylines/histogram/6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff'
            ]

for i in path_list:
    s = re.search(r"\/\w+\/\w+\/\w+\/([^_/]+)", i)
    if s:
        print(s.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
offline-deployer-list
normal.jsp
hbase-env.sh
LICENSE-tesh
geronimo
catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1
geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd
6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use split?

```
>>> list = [x.split("/")[-1].split("_")[0] for x in path_list]
>>> list
['offline-deployer-list', 'normal.jsp', 'hbase-env.sh', 'LICENSE-tesh', 'geronimo', 'catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1', 'geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd', '6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT']
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to use regex because it is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very pythonic solution.

```
import re

path_list = ['/Users/buggylines/histogram/offline-deployer-list_b7bacc7fdb-0e0e08077c_GERONIMO-2886_635_histogrambuglines_635.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/normal.jsp_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/hbase-env.sh_aa0c2c26dd-90188cc2a4_GERONIMO-4597_1293_histogrambuglines_1293.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/LICENSE-tesh_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo_dcce59ae71-8f5c1aa7a1_GERONIMO-5661_1554_histogrambuglines_54.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/catalina-6.0.18-G678601.jar.sha1_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/geronimo-naming-1.0.xsd_544dee5179-40a2ae1d41_GERONIMO-1027_131_histogrambuglines_131.diff',
         '/Users/buggylines/histogram/6.0.18-G678601.README.TXT_cd1ec17e43-4ebc5e8021_GERONIMO-5702_1573_histogrambuglines_785.diff'
        ]


filename_re = re.compile(r'^\/Users\/buggylines\/histogram\/(?P<filename>[A-Za-z0-9-.]+)_')

filename = []
for item in path_list:
    filename_match = filename_re.search(item)
    if filename_match:
         filename.append(filename_match.group('filename'))

print(filename)
```